# SQL bigquery: Bool column for previous month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to write in sql a bool column for id_customers:

```
If there is a purchase this month and if there is a purchase in the past, then 1. 
If there is a purchase this month, but not in the past, then 0. 

First frame:
id_customers | sale_date

Total frame:
id_customers | sale_date | bool
```

Thank you for advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help ensure that your question is unambiguous.

Comment: It's not open database

Comment: Please try something, show what you've done and any particular question/issue, otherwise it seems you expect someone to do your work. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a boolean per customer on whether the purchase this month is the first month of purchases for the customer.  That would be something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(sale_date) < date_trunc('month', current_date)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_repeat_customer
from t
group by customer
having max(sale_date) >= date_trunc('month', current_date);
```

This uses Postgres syntax, but that is arbitrary because you haven't specified a database.

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. If I have purchase in this month, I should check previous month